# Hover text for chat starboard messages

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars

In chat, starred messages appear in the panel to the right but are truncated to a certain length. Rather than have to follow the link to a new page, it would be useful to be able to hover over a starred message and see the full text.

Would there be demand for this?

Would this be practical to implement?

Does anyone have reason to object to this?

Comment: I would definitely like to see this! (I just posted a duplicate feature request.) Also, fyi, [the truncation happens server side](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/chats/stars/89), so a user-script can't really easily be made to do this (although perhaps it's possible to retrieve the full text of a message give its ID through other means).

Answer (score 3):

I agree there is room for improvement.

Chat rooms tend to be about quick actions, so it should be simple just to see the full message quickly and easily within the chat room.

The current options are not really quick, and take you to a new tab/page and show either message history, or full transcript for a room.
Neither is ideal just to show a truncated starred message.

### Alternative idea

The hover over info idea is fine, but there is still a *slight* delay waiting for it to appear.

What about showing the rest of a truncated message by clicking on it, and the full message is displayed by creating space downover, and pushing any messages below it down a bit.

And it could return to being truncated (e.g.):

- 10 seconds after clicking
- Clicking same starred message again
- Clicking another starred message moves previously clicked one up,
  then drops newly clicked message down

Similar to an *accordion* style setup:  [JS/jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/aff4vL5g/624/).

Not that design - the current chat room design and layout should remain, that example is just to show how clicking would move messages up/down to create space and show a full message.